# I want to convert list items to separate integers & add them after

Tags: python, list

I have a file full of lines contain words & numbers 
I want these numbers to be found then summed 
What I wrote is:

```
import re

fhand = open('ReSample.txt')

for line in fhand:   
    y = re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
    for item in y:
        item = int(item)
        total = total + item    
print total
```

The error is total is not defined!!!

File lines sample

> Writing programs (or programming) is a very creative  and rewarding
>   activity.  You can write programs for  3036 many reasons, ranging from
>   making your living to solving 7209 a difficult data analysis problem
>   to having fun to helping

```
Desired output >>>  3036 + 7209 + ......
```

Can you fix my code without critical changes please?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: It is hard to fix it without a sample of the input and desired output.

Comment: You're iterating over `y`, but then reassigning `y`. Did you mean `item = int(item)`?

Comment: is this line correct `y = int(y)` ? Did you mean `y = int(item)` ?

Comment: `Can you fix my code without critical changes please?` Can you show us the file contents please?

Comment: Yes I corrected it to
for item in y:
        item = int(item)
        total = total + item

Comment: File lines are like these:

Writing programs (or programming) is a very creative 
and rewarding activity.  You can write programs for 
3036 many reasons, ranging from making your living to solving 7209
a difficult data analysis problem to having fun to helping

I want to add 3036 + 7209 + ...........

Comment: But `total` is not definied. You are using it to assign it to `total` which is not possible since it's not definied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use the variable `total` to add `item` to it and assign the sum to `total`. By the first execution of your loop, `total` is not definied.

Please consider this approach:

```
import re

fhand = open('ReSample.txt')

total=0

for line in fhand:   
    y = re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
    for item in y:
        item = int(item)
        total = total + item   

print(total)
```

The output is `10245`.